# Change URL access of API via htaccess

Tags: api, apache, express, .htaccess, port

In my PC, I have express API running with PM2 on port 3000 and use Apache as web service on regular port (80) which can be accessed via http://localhost via browser.
[image]
On documentroot folder, i added htaccess file with following code :

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:3000/$1 [P,L]
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:3000/ [P,L]
```

So when I access : http://localhost, that show the root api endpoint becase that rewrite rule.
[image]
Is it safe or what the impact will i get if I did that?

Comment: It is impossible to answer to such a question. What is safe? I mean how do you define "safe"? And how should we say what the impact is for you? We do not know your situation or what you are doing...

Comment: I read about create virtualhost on apache and didnt find yet article about using htaccess like i did. I mean, will it causes error both on apache or my API someday if i use that method (htaccess for change access from domain.com:3000 to domain.com)??

Comment: Why should something that works suddenly throw an error "someday"? And why didn't you find any "article" about creating a virtualhost on an apache http server? I would suggest you take a look into the documentation then!